# Sharepoint GetListItems with a query not returning results

Tags: sharepoint

When I call GetListItems with the following Query:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Contains>
            <FieldRef Name="Author"/>
            <Value Type="Text">Bob</Value>
        </Contains>
    </Where>
</Query>;
```

I get back a list with one row like this:

```
<z:row ows_ID="411" .... ows_ClientID="string;#7779" ... />
```

But, when I call the same list, but with this query:

```
<Query>
    <Where>
        <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name="ClientID"/>
            <Value Type="Number">7779</Value>
        </Eq>
    </Where>
</Query>;
```

I get back no rows:

```
<GetListItemsResponse ...>  
    <GetListItemsResult ...>    
        <listitems ...> 
            <rs:data ItemCount="0" ....
```

Anyone have any idea why I'm not getting back that same row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `string;#7779` is clearly not `7779` nor does it claim to be a numeric type ;-)

Anyway, try:

1. <del>`<Value Type='Calculated'>string;#7779</Value>`</del> (see comment) or;
2. `<Value Type='Text'>7779</Value>` (note not "Number")

Happy coding.

---

Protip: Use the [U2U CAML Query Builder](http://www.u2u.net/res/Tools/CamlQueryBuilder.aspx) to speed up "finding the quirks".

Comment: That didn't work, but `<Value Type='Text'>7779</Value>` did. I swear, I had already tried that and got an error. Oh well. Thank you. (edit: posted this before your update. #2 worked.)

Comment: @Jacob Eggers Yeah -- I'm an edit-addict :( I really wish SO allowed posting in an "unpublished" mode.